# Count of Messages consumed by Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka

In our application there is publisher and consumer, via swagger we can request publisher to send specific type of data, data volume can range between 10K to 100K. Then consumer receives the same and processes further.

As its a specific type of data set, we need to know exact count as if, how much was published and how much was consumed. Earlier we used MQ so we knew that 10K is published and now MQ is empty so all are consumed but in kafka we are not able to figure out.

Is there any way to find this out, I know we can start counting in code and print/store somewhere but anything provided by Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka does not store this message count information, but it does store offsets, which you can query from a consumer to find where it started from, its current position, and how many messages are left to consume. However, this is constantly a moving target.

In pseudo-code, you would essentially need to do have external storage/database around the consumer code

```
long count = 0;  // or lookup previous value by client-id, topic-partition, etc from some storage
try {
  while (consumerRunning) {
    // poll ...
    for each record {
        process(record);
        count++;
    }
  }
} catch (WakeupException e) { // and other exceptions

} finally {
  updateCount(count); // save back to storage
}
```

While you can aggregate consumer bytes-in JMX metrics, for example, that requires external metrics collection processes.

Overall, there's usually not a need for this in Kafka since you can always re-wind a consumer's offsets (or not commit them at all), and consumers can
scale out, so counting could be inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. this means there is no out of box feature from Kafka?

Comment: Outside of counting offsets, manually, no

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your question and description,

It's looks like you are looking for a way to know that your consumers consumed all the messages from the topic

kafka saves in internal topic for its consumer of consumer groups

the current offset of partition,

The end offset,

And  end-(minus)-current equals the lag,

how much messages your consumers in the consumer group needs to read on in order to finish up the lag to 0,

you can issue consumer-groups describe command cli to see this information ,

if the lag is 0 means you finished reading all the messages in the topic

Comment: Thanks you.. again wanted to avoid manual work.,